# "You think he's a jackass now..."

Tags: better-call-saul

In the *Better Call Saul* episode "Magic Man" Jimmy is trying to convince Kim to let him help her get her pro-bono client to accept the deal rather than going to trial and says something like, "You think he's a jackass now, wait till he gets back from that clown college..."

Is he implying that prison is so bad that it can actually make you dumber? Or does he mean, make him a more hardened criminal?

Answer (score 5):

It’s widely believed in the United States that prisons make people more traumatized and also more likely to commit crimes when they leave than they were when they were sent there. At the very least, it’s a trope in movies and TV. In *The Shawshank Redemption*, Andy half-jokes to Red, “I had to come to prison to become a criminal”.

Research seems to only slightly support the trope. [This paper](https://www.publicsafety.gc.ca/cnt/rsrcs/pblctns/ffct-prsn/index-en.aspx) reports:

> The recidivism rate for offenders who were imprisoned as opposed to given a community sanction were similar. In addition, longer prison sentences were not associated with reduced recidivism. In fact, the opposite was found. Longer sentences were associated with a 3% increase in recidivism.

So Jimmy is suggesting that this young defendant will become a more hardened criminal if he goes to prison and so it’s in the public good for Kim to violate ethics to make sure that doesn’t happen.

Comment: "Jackass" is different than hardened criminal -- if he had implied that he would become even more likely to commit crimes and more serious crimes, that is easily understood. But if Mike is implying something more horrible, that prisons actually cause PTSD or something and therefore the inmates become less able to deal with the world when they get out, I think that is the more interesting interpretation.

Comment: @releseabe Mike? Did you mean Jimmy? Perhaps the point of my answer is clouded by the concept of recidivism. My answer is: he means "more hardened criminal". In this particular case, the "criminal" isn’t hard at all, just a kid who made a mistake. Basically if you go from not at all a criminal to being a criminal, you are a more hardened criminal. Just like Andy in *Shawshank…*. I think the PTSD is a widely believed (or assumed) cause of being a more hardened criminal after prison. Plus association with criminals during incarceration.

Comment: Yes, Jimmy. Anyway, "jackass" means to me a foolish person, not a criminal. The guy is clearly sort of a dope already and I think that Jimmy did mean to use jackass in that sense. It is an interesting effect of prison if so, I had never heard of this. But PTSD is not good for the brain -- there are I believe measurable effects on the brain, like shrinkage of the hippocampus iirc.

Comment: @releseabe You might be focusing too much on the word jackass. I’m not sure what your vision of what a criminal is, but the defendant in question was not at all contesting that he committed a crime. From that definition, he’s a criminal - he has committed a crime. And anyway, it really doesn’t matter exactly what Jimmy meant by "jackass", because what he’s really trying to say is that going to prison will start him on a downward spiral where he will spend the rest of his life committing crimes and doing time.

Comment: Nothing interesting in Jimmy stating the obvious "Prison will make him a worse criminal." Besides "jackass" he also uses the term "clown college" which further implies that prison produces "clowns."